Assuming Euclidean Metric in $\mathbb{R}$
I came across an exercise asking to prove that for a metric space $(X,d)$, with $p \in X$, the distance to p is a continuous map. I.e. that $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = d(x,p)$ for $x \in X$ is continuous.
I'm happy getting to $|d(x,p)-d(c,p)| \leq d(x,c) < \delta = \varepsilon$, but I don't see how we are able to assume that $d_{\mathbb{R}}(d(x,p),d(p,c))$ will be given by the standard Euclidean metric. Do we always assume that $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard absolute value metric? Is it possible to prove the result for a general $d_{\mathbb{R}}(d(x,p),d(p,c))$?
Continuity in a metric space: Let $(X,d_X), (Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces, $c \in X$ and $f:X \rightarrow Y$. Then f is said to be continuous at c if $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that whenever $x \in X$ satisfies $d_X(x,c) < \delta$, we have $d_Y(f(x),f(c)) < \varepsilon$. I guess my question is if and how we know that $d_Y$ will be the standard Euclidean metric. Thanks.

For any metric $d: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$, so $d(x,p) \in \mathbb{R}$, so you can typically use the standard metric of $\mathbb{R}$. I don't understand your question, "Do we always assume $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard absolute value metric?". Can you elaborate on that?

Yes, the assumption is that $\mathbb{R}$ has the usual metric. Otherwise, the statement will not be true. Try to find counterexamples when you define, for example, the discrete metric on $\mathbb{R}$, which is $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$, and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\ne y$.

Yes, unless otherwise stated, $\Bbb R$ always has its usual topology, induced for instance by the Euclidean metric.
